# How to force a Google Protobuf generated java code to implement a user-defined interface

Tags: java, gradle, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I am working on a service serialization enhancement to introduce Google Protobuf. One additional design flexibility, I am attempting to accomplish is to enhance the ease of extensibility of the serialization mechanisms. The idea I got is to define an interface that contains a subset of the *Builder.java Protobuf generated java code, then append the generated *Builder.java class to implement that newly defined interface. My questions are:

1. How I can append that interface syntax to the generated class?
2. Does Protobuf have a native way to support such a scenario?
3. If Google Protobuf doesn't support that approach natively, is there a different, better approach to do it? (other than encapsulating the *Builder.java class in a wrapper object?)
4. In light of Protobuf's best practices, does anyone thinks doing a code-gen that generates and appends the needed code to the *Builder.java at the coding build stage is feasible?

I have looked in blog posts and it seems the way that people are implementing it is using gradle to append the interface implementation syntax `implements user_defined_interface`into the protobuf generated Java code *Builder.java class